# run a query from a column

Tags: sql, plsql

What i want: i have a table with queries, i need to make a query that runs one of the values in that column

ie:

```
queryname    query
Chips        select * from chips_table c join all_stores s on c.id=s.id where s.loc>213...
...          ...
```

I know i want the result from the above query, how can i run a procedure or script or view or whatnot like

```
getme(Chips)
```

and this to run the

```
select * from chips_table c join all_stores s on c.id=s.id where s.loc>213...
```

Comment: Not a pl/sql guy but execute immediate or something like that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the results afterwards, but for PL/SQL processing you may use something like:

```
-- Function to open and return the cursor for the query based on query name
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_cursor (in_queryname IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
    c_query SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_query queries.query%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT query INTO v_query FROM queries WHERE queryname = in_queryname;
    OPEN c_query FOR v_query;
    RETURN c_query;
END;

-- Example of use
DECLARE
    c_query SYS_REFCURSOR;
    some_variable INTEGER;
    another_variable INTEGER;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        FETCH c_query INTO some_variable, another_variable;
        EXIT WHEN c_query%NOTFOUND;
        -- Do someting!
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_query;
EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
    NULL; -- Log the error!
END;
```

Comment: Unfortunately i need to create a view with it :(

Comment: To create a view just use: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW ' || queryname || ' AS ' || query;